# Choices-js - programmatically change the selected value

Tags: javascript, choices.js

I am using [Choices-js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) to create a custom select element. The user can either use the select dropdown or some buttons to select their choice. On click of the button, I would like for the select dropdown to automatically take the value that the button is passing. The way I normally do this with a standard `select` element, `selectEle.value = 'val';`, doesn't seem to be working. I tried to dispatch a change event to see if that might trigger the value to change, but that doesn't seem to work either.

```js
const standardSel = document.getElementById('standard');
const choicesSel = document.getElementById('choices');

choices = new Choices(choicesSel, {
  searchEnabled: false
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    let selectEle = e.target.closest('.container').querySelector('select');
    // Set the value of the select box
    selectEle.value = 'ipsum';
    
    // Trigger change event
    selectEle.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
});
```

```css
select, .choices {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  margin-bottom:15px!important;
}
  .choices__inner {
    min-height:initial!important;
  }

.container {
  display:block;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/10.2.0/choices.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <select id="standard">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    <option value="ipsum">Ipsum</option>
    <option valule="dolor">Dolor</option>
  </select>

  <button>Select "Ipsum"</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <select id="choices">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    <option value="ipsum">Ipsum</option>
    <option valule="dolor">Dolor</option>
  </select>

  <button>Select "Ipsum"</button>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/10.2.0/choices.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the choice's variable and not the select itself.

Then you can use `setValue` or `setChoiceByValue` on that object.

setValue has to be an array of something but setChoiceByValue can be the string itself. [gitHub docs](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices)

```
choices.setValue(['ipsum']);
```

or

```
choices.setChoiceByValue('ipsum');
```

I also made a tweak to the variables, so that you could easily use it on multiple selects.

```js
const standardSel = document.getElementById('standard');
const choicesSel = document.getElementById('choices');

const choiceSelects = {
  "choices" : new Choices(choicesSel, {searchEnabled: false}),
  "standard" : new Choices(standardSel, {searchEnabled: false})
};

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
    let selectEle = e.target.closest('.container').querySelector('select');
    
    //choices.setValue(['ipsum']); or
    choiceSelects[selectEle.id].setChoiceByValue('ipsum');
  }
});
```

```css
select, .choices {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  margin-bottom:15px!important;
}
  .choices__inner {
    min-height:initial!important;
  }

.container {
  display:block;
  margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/10.2.0/choices.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <select id="standard">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    <option value="ipsum">Ipsum</option>
    <option valule="dolor">Dolor</option>
  </select>

  <button>Select "Ipsum"</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <select id="choices">
    <option value="">--Select One--</option>
    <option value="lorem">Lorem</option>
    <option value="ipsum">Ipsum</option>
    <option valule="dolor">Dolor</option>
  </select>

  <button>Select "Ipsum"</button>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/choices.js/10.2.0/choices.min.js"></script>
```